# Installing Ubuntu Server on a laptop

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-server

I want to use Ubuntu Server for learning purposes. Of course I won't buy a server for that so I wonder if I can install it on a laptop and then connect to it through local network or `ssh`. Is that possible?

Comment: Why not? Ubuntu Server doesn't try to identify some special "flag" that indicates that the hardware is a server, it will just install the server version of ubuntu (which is basically a lightweight version with the minimal packages of the Desktop version)

Comment: Short answer: Yes​​​​​​​​​​​​. Long answer: Yes, probably.

Comment: As everyone has said, yes it can be done, quite easily.... one thing I would suggest, is that if your laptop already has Windows on (as many do!) then you either "dual boot" (but you can only run one at any one time) or you run the Ubuntu server in a VM using, for example, VirtualBox... you'll be able to learn more things including networking between the two - so that both machines can talk to each other :)

Comment: Ubuntu server is basically just Ubuntu without a GUI.

Answer (score 4):

A laptop can actually be a quite good small home server or a small machine to learn on. You dont need to occupy screens, keyboards and other things you might need to set up a regular server. The main drawback is power. But if it's just for learning purposes then I think is brilliant.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to have some fun. Ubuntu Server is quite small, so why not virtualize, maximize your hardware's potential and have multiple Servers. There are many Virtualization application [OpenVZ](http://www.openvz.org), [Xen](http://www.xen.org), [VMPlayer](https://www.vmware.com/products/player) and [vSphere Hypervisor](https://www.vmware.com/products/vsphere-hypervisor/). All which are free.

Once you have a few Ubuntu Servers running you can experiment with joining them in a cluster of your choice. Like using [SingleSignOn](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SingleSignOn), or joining a [Windows Domain](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ActiveDirectoryWinbindHowto)(that's always fun). Setup your Server as a [NAS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1266/how-to-set-up-ubuntu-server-as-a-nas) or [Media Server](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MediaTomb).

Your possibilities are endless. [Ubuntu Server Capabilities](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Servers)

Comment: Yeah I did that actually. I have Ubuntu server on a VM and Ubuntu Desktop on a laptop which also has server on it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need an entire laptop - you can buy a cheap RasperryPi and install Ubuntu on that. It won't be particularly powerful - but can be great for basic learning.

There's a guide here on installed Ubuntu on a RasperryPi.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi